# ¿SpeechSynthesizer en español? (C#)

Tags: c#

estaba ojeando una clase de C# llamada Speech. Hice un pequeño programa de prueba para ver como sonaba, y me parecio muy interesante todo. Ahora, el tema es que la unica voz instalada en el sistema, es en ingles (por supuesto) y se hace llamar por "Anna".

Por supuesto que si escribo palabras en español, al ser una voz en ingles lo pronuncia extraño. Por ahi lei que se debe instalar la voz en español, pero donde consigo eso? Tengo tambien la intencion de probar el reconocimiento de voz... afectara tambien el tema del ingles en el reconocimiento? (creo que seguramente si..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para windows 10:

Inicio -> Configuracion -> tiempo e idioma -> región e idioma, Agregar Idioma, Adicionas el idioma español si no esta.

Una vez instalado o si ya esta, selecciona el idioma en la lista, y continuación opciones, en opciones de idioma -> voz, seleccionar descargar.

Saludos,

Comment: Tengo windows 7, pero tu respuesta es bastante util y ya me da la idea mas o menos de como va el asunto con esas voces e idiomas...